# Asp.Net MVC @helper template in different folder than App_Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, templates, html-helper

Like I said in the title of my question, is it possible to put the @helper template of cshtml file in a folder other than App_Code to be visible by my views?

I discovered the [very nice article from ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx) but I don't found any solution to my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can, if you write them as extension methods (static methods of a static class). Something like:

```
public static string AMethod(this HtmlHelper html, int arg)
...
```

Lets you call the method in a cshtml file as

```
@Html.AMethod(5)
```

Comment: sorry, but I want razor helpers and not any other kind of extensions (HtmlHelper and such)... please check this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx