# ASP.Net MVC @helper on App_Code Subfolder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It's possible to have `@helper` template's in a subfolder of `App_Code`?

I know that is impossible to have them **outside** this folder, as seem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689333/asp-net-mvc-helper-template-in-different-folder-than-app-code)

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: @GSerg I cannot find the Helpers on my `.cshtml` files

Comment: Works for me. `@NewFolder1.whatever.SomeHelper(42)` renders `@helper SomeHelper` from `App_Code/NewFolder1/whatever.cshtml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A think just some bug. After I restarted Visual Studio, it worked just as expected. Great thanks to @GSerj!